# Как получить создателя файла в git

Tags: java, git

Всем привет!
Как можно получить автора какого-либо файла, сохраненного в git репозитории, с помощью Java (использую класс JGit для подключения к git) ?
И вообще возможно ли?

Comment: Ну автором файла ведь является тот, кто сделал первый коммит в этот файл. Соответственно, задача сводится к поиску первого коммита в нужном файле.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Подскажите, какой класс использовать для получения коммита для файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить все комиты для какого-то определенного файла можно так

```
Git git = getGit(); //ваш метод по получению ссылки на Git
Iterable < RevCommit > commits = git.log().addPath('/path/to/file').call(); //получить все коммиты для определенного файла
for (RevCommit commit: commits) {
    System.out.println('committer email : ' + commit.getAuthorIdent().getEmailAddress());
    System.out.println('committer name : ' + commit.getAuthorIdent().getName());
    System.out.println('when commit : ' + commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! 

 Я реализовал так.
 
    private String getAuthor(Repository repository, String filePath) {
        Git git = new Git(repository);
        BlameResult blameResult = null;
        try {
            blameResult = git.blame().setFilePath( filePath ).call();
        } catch (GitAPIException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int size = blameResult.getResultContents().size();
        if( size > 0 ) {
            return blameResult.getSourceAuthor( 0 ).getName();
        }

        return null;
    }
 
 Т.е. почти тоже самое, что и у Вас.

Comment: Каша какая-то получилась. Как бы то ни было, всем откликнувшимся большое спасибо! P.S. Почему-то не получилось сделать, что отзыв был полезен.

Comment: Вы можете пометить ответ как верный